# I Have SQL query in this format select column B from table A where id = """ + column B value + """, How to use .format method of python instead of +

Tags: python

I Have SQL query in this format select   column B from table A where id = """ + column B value + """, How to use `.format` method of python instead of `+`

Column B value is getting replaced dynamically, I want to use `.format` concat, how to use that instead of `+` in sql query.

Comment: You shouldn't use `.format()` to create SQL queries, you should use prepared statements.

Comment: I want something like this : select id from student where id = "{}".format(ID); As of now its not working.

Comment: Use a cursor and `cursor.execute()` with placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.format()` to create the query, that allows for SQL-injection. Use `Cursor.execute()` with placeholders and a tuple of values.

If you're using MySQL Connector, it looks like this:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(database='world')
cur = cns.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT colB FROM tableA WHERE id = %s", (id))
colB = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately its a specific requirement to use format concat , howcan we specify that ? Thanks for ur help

Comment: Why is it a specific requirement to write buggy code?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you. The whole point of homework is for you to figure it out yourself from what you've been taught. Read your textbook.

Comment: my initial question was releated to format method only, its your thought that format allows for sql injcetion which is not the case.

Comment: Post what you've tried, and maybe someone will show how to correct it.

Comment: Have tried this :  def select_getspecificID(ID):
        rn: Query String.
        
        sql = """
              select id, name,  from job where id = ""{}.format(ID)"";"""

        
        return sql

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment, so you can do proper formatting.